# How to get Sitecore user create date with PowerShell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm building a report with PowerShell, but I can't find where is the creation date for the users. I need filtering by dates range and later get custom properties.

```
Get-User -Filter 'default\*' `
        | Where-Object { $_.Profile.??? -gt (get-date 2019-01-01) } `
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot get user creation date from the Sitecore `User` class directly.

What you can do instead is getting `MembershipUser` object first and using it's `CreationDate` property like:

```
$users = Get-User -Filter 'default\*'

foreach($user in $users) {
    $muser = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GetUser($user.Name)
    "$($user.Name) $($muser.CreationDate)"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marek, but from `MembershipUser` we can get custom properties?